# Concatenate Unequal Length List & String

Tags: python-2.7

I trying to combine some data points of unequal lengths and different types into a new list.

```
str1 = "somestring"
list1 = [1,2,3]
```

So, how to get list2 such that it is:

```
[somestring1,somestring2,somestring3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you expect as result a list of strings, try the following, using list comprenhension:

```
str1 = "somestring"
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

result = [str1 + str(e) for e in list1]
print result
```

**Output:**

```
['somestring1', 'somestring2', 'somestring3']
```